# For each wrap every 4 elements in a div using existing ¿counter?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach, counter

i have to modify this code, to echo every 4 thumbs (extraimage) inside a div...

I searched on Stackoverflow but all answers talk about setting a counter, i want to avoid this (if possible) using a counter that is already counting the extraimages.. i think it most be as easy as a conditional

if counter extraimages==3 echo div.. but how do i go back to 0 ,, or maybe i am missunderstanding the way to do this..

This is the part of the code where the array is set and the for each is set.

```
<?php if($extraimagecount >0){?>
<?php foreach ($extraimage as $key=>$value){?>



<?php }?>


<?php }?>

<a href="<?php echo DATA_DIR."/".$id."/".$this->get_variable('firstimage');?>" >
    <img src="<?php echo DATA_DIR."/".$id."/".$this->get_variable('firstimage');?>" class="minis"/>
</a>



<?php if($extraimagecount >0){
$rotate=1;
$tumppr=0;

?>
<?php foreach ($extraimage as $key=>$value){

$rotate=$rotate+1;
?>



<a href="<?php echo DATA_DIR."/".$id."/".$value['image'];?>" >
    <img src="<?php echo DATA_DIR."/".$id."/t_".$value['image'];?>" class="minis"/>
</a>



<?php 



if($rotate==8)
{
    $rotate=0;
    $tumppr=$tumppr+1;

    ?>




    <?php 

}
?>

<?php }?>


<?php }?>
</div>


<?php 


 $lftstr="";
 $rgtstr="";
if($extraimagecount >0)
{
$extcnt=count($extraimage); 
$extcntnew=$extcnt+1;

 $extdivide=intval(($extcntnew/8));
 $extmode=($extcntnew % 8);


for($i=0;$i<$extdivide;$i++)   //************ For Right Arrow ***************/
{
?>
    <div id="rgt_<?php echo $i;?>" class="rgt" <?php if($i >0 || $extmode ==0){?>style="display: none;"<?php }?>  ><img class="rgtimg" src="images/rnext.png"></div>
<?php 
    $rgtstr=$rgtstr.$i.'_';
}

for($ii=1;$ii<$extdivide;$ii++)   //************ For left Arrow ***************/
{
    ?>
    <div id="lft_<?php echo $ii;?>" class="lft" style="display: none;" ><img class="lftimg" src="images/lnext.png"></div>
    <?php

    $lftstr=$lftstr.$ii.'_';


}

if($extmode >0)
{
?>
    <div id="lft_<?php echo $extdivide;?>" class="lft" style="display: none;" ><img class="lftimg" src="images/lnext.png"></div>

<?php 

    $lftstr=$lftstr.$extdivide.'_';
}

}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you take a look into the code.. can i use the counter $rotate... what is the reason of $rotate in the code, what is used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually quite easy, use the % operator. a%b will return the remainder of a/b. heres how you use it

```
for($i=0;$i<9;$i++)
{
    echo $i%3." ";
}
```

this will print out 
0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2

You can then use this to create groups of 4 in your case.

Comment: Thanks, but can you take a look into the code.. can i use the counter $rotate... what is the reason of $rotate in the code, what is used for?

Comment: Well from what I see $rotate is just being added up for every image so it will be equal to sizeof($extraimage). Then it adds one to $tumppr if there was more than 8 extra images. Both of these variables dont get used once in the script. they both are used as counters but dont get used in any conditionals, output or add any functionality in any way unless code was excluded from the post.

Comment: well the code could definitely use some cleaning up and im sure it would make things alot more clear. did you remove any code from this chunk or is that all of it?

Comment: actually I remove some html tables , but i didnt take out any of the php

Comment: Well assuming that $rotate is used it looks like it resets every 8th image where it says if($rotate==8). If you need to do 4s you could do if($rotate==0 || $rotate == 4)

Comment: Yeah i think thats because the limit of images for each user is 8.. i will try thanks. DO i have to set the first after this? $rotate=$rotate+1;.. because $rotate will never be 0.. thats why i have all this doubts